# Saving the image names and bounding box coordinates in different file formats in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, save

I've written a Matlab code to crop an image with respect to a mask.

```
function Crop_Img = Crop_Xray(Img,Mask)
% Find borders
vertical_profile = sum(Mask,2);
horizontal_profile = sum(Mask);
indexes = find(vertical_profile >0);
upper = indexes(1);
lower = indexes(end);
indexes = find(horizontal_profile > 0);
left = indexes(1);
right = indexes(end);
% Crop Img
Crop_Img = Img(upper:lower, left:right);
end
```

I would like to save the individual image file names (*.png) and their respective bounding box co-ordinates [upper: lower, left: right] exactly in the format I have mentioned, in adjacent columns to a .xls, .txt, and .mat file. How should I do that?

Comment: "in the format I have mentioned" -> where did you mention this? I don't see it. And do you want to save the information to an Excel file, a text file **and** a MAT-file? Or is one of those formats sufficient?

Comment: You mention image file names, but I do not see them appear anywhere in your code. If you want to automate the naming procedure, you will have to somehow incorporate the name a file should get into your code. Then you can use the following:

- **Excel file**: follow instruction at [this page](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-excel-spreadsheets.html)

- **.txt file**: use fprintf;

- **mat file**: use save('filename.mat','variable1','variableN');

Comment: Do you want to create a list of all of your modified images aling with the additional information?